# Table-view rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hey guys when I show talbeview there are a lot of empty rows... How can I make the number of rows shown exactly equal to [NSARRAY COUNT]

I am sure

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

return the right number of rows that it should show

Comment: Add some code please for any kind of help. Put tableView Datasource methods and method where your array prepared.

Comment: - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ 
 return [quiz.questions count];
}

Although the [questions count] returns 5 the tableView will show more than 5 rows with empty extra rows... How can i not show them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the table footerView to a view that doesn't render anything (but not nil).

tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView allocate] init] autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right place and really have the answer already. Here it is in code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [yourDataArrayName count];
}
```

Substitute the actual name of your table for *tableView* and the actual name of your array for *yourDataArrayName*, obviously.

Comment: What i mean is that... say this method returns 5 but the tableview shows a lot more than 5 rows and those extra rows are empty... Now I want this tableview to show exactly 5 rows

Comment: If there are 5 items in the array the tableview will only draw 5 rows. Are you sure you don't have array elements with empty values/dictionaries in them? Put a breakpoint on the return line and when the app execution pauses on it, type "print [yourArrayName count]" (without the quotes) to ensure it actually has just 5.

Comment: The array has only 5 elements... it is footerview stuff... thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right place and really have the answer already. Here it is in code: 
try it may be helped....

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return totalRows;
  }
  totalRows= (you  want so no. of rows )

and

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %i",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
      cell.highlighted = YES
  }